java apache poi close subtotal and the excel is corrupted
i use java apache poi to generate pivot table and when i use setOutline(false) to let the pivot table show in parallel form rather than in outline form, it will add subtotal row.  That's weird. and then i try to use setDefaultSubtotal(false) to disable the subtotal, and then the generated excel were damaged. when i open the table, it noted that "We found a problem with some content in 'pivottable.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? if you trust the source of this workbook, click YeYesNo".
the code as below:
@Test
    public void rowLabelTest() {
        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

            Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
            Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
            Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);

            row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product");
            row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Region");
            row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Sales");

            row2.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product A");
            row2.createCell(1).setCellValue("North");
            row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(100);

            row3.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product B");
            row3.createCell(1).setCellValue("South");
            row3.createCell(2).setCellValue(150);

            XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot Table");
            AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:C3", workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, new CellReference("A5"), sheet);

            int productFieldIndex = 0;
            int regionFieldIndex = 1;

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(productFieldIndex);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(regionFieldIndex);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(productFieldIndex).setOutline(false);
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(regionFieldIndex).setOutline(false);

            CTPivotFields fields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();
            CTPivotField pivotFieldProduct = fields.getPivotFieldArray(productFieldIndex);
            CTPivotField pivotFieldRegion = fields.getPivotFieldArray(regionFieldIndex);

            if (pivotFieldProduct != null) {
                pivotFieldProduct.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
            }

            if (pivotFieldRegion != null) {
                pivotFieldRegion.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
            }

            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("pivottable.xlsx")) {
                workbook.write(fileOut);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

enter image description here
i tried to remove the subtotal row

While creating the pivot table, Apache POI adds as much field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) as there are rows in source. This is, because they don't have a look at the data, they are assuming this max count of different values. This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening.
But if we want changing defaults, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are.
So we need at least as much items, as are different ones in the data, as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>. And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.
The challenge is to get the unique items of the fields to count the needed items and to build the cache from.
Your example improved:
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

class CreatePivotTableTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./PivotTable.xlsx") ) {
           
   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
   
   XSSFSheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet();
   
   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"Product", "Region", "Sales"},
    new Object[]{"Product A", "North", 100},
    new Object[]{"Product B", "South", 150}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Number) {
      cell.setCellValue(((Number)rowData[c]).doubleValue());
     }
    }
   }

   XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot Table");
   AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:C" + data.length, workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, new CellReference("A5"), dataSheet);

   int productFieldIndex = 0;
   int regionFieldIndex = 1;

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(productFieldIndex);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(regionFieldIndex);

   /*   
    Apache poi adds as much field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) as there are rows in source. 
    This is, because they don't have a look at the data, they are assuming this max count of different values. 
    This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. 

    But if we want changing defaults, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are.

    So we need at least as much items, as are different ones in the data, as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/> 

    And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.
   */
   
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(productFieldIndex).setOutline(false);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(regionFieldIndex).setOutline(false);

   CTPivotFields fields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();
   CTPivotField pivotFieldProduct = fields.getPivotFieldArray(productFieldIndex);
   CTPivotField pivotFieldRegion = fields.getPivotFieldArray(regionFieldIndex);

   if (pivotFieldProduct != null) {
    //determine unique labels in column
    java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (int r = source.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < source.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
     uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(productFieldIndex)));
    }
    //System.out.println(uniqueItems);

    //build pivot items and cache
    int i = 0;
    for (String item : uniqueItems) {
     //take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
     pivotFieldProduct.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
     pivotFieldProduct.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
     //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
     pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(productFieldIndex)
      .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
     i++;
    }

    //set pivot field settings
    pivotFieldProduct.setDefaultSubtotal(false); // no subtotals for this field

    //remove further items
    if (pivotFieldProduct.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; //let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
    for (int k = pivotFieldProduct.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
     pivotFieldProduct.getItems().removeItem(k);
    }
    pivotFieldProduct.getItems().setCount(i);
   }

   if (pivotFieldRegion != null) {
    //determine unique labels in column
    java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (int r = source.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < source.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
     uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(regionFieldIndex)));
    }
    //System.out.println(uniqueItems);

    //build pivot items and cache
    int i = 0;
    for (String item : uniqueItems) {
     //take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
     pivotFieldRegion.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
     pivotFieldRegion.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
     //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
     pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(regionFieldIndex)
      .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
     i++;
    }

    //set pivot field settings
    pivotFieldRegion.setDefaultSubtotal(false); // no subtotals for this field

    //remove further items
    if (pivotFieldRegion.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; //let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
    for (int k = pivotFieldRegion.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
     pivotFieldRegion.getItems().removeItem(k);
    }
    pivotFieldRegion.getItems().setCount(i);
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}

